# How to disable tooltips for the highcharts-regression plugin?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've created a simple Highcharts scatter plot with three data points.  It uses the [highcharts-regression](https://github.com/streamlinesocial/highcharts-regression) plug-in to add a series showing the linear regression line.  I would like tooltips to display for the data points but *not* for the regression line, so I have disabled the tooltip like this:

```
series: [{
  regression: true,
  name: 'Test input',
  color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
  data: [
    [1, 1],
    [2, 3],
    [3, 9],       
  ],
  regressionSettings: {
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false // <---- I expect this to disable the tooltip
    },
  }
}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f34mza2q/1/

As you can see from the jsfiddle, the tooltips still pop up for the regression line.  How can I turn off the tooltips here (and still keep them for the data points)?

I've tried a couple of other things:

- adding a **style: 'display: "none"'** to regressionSettings.tooltip
- setting regressionSettings.enableMouseTracking to false

Neither seemed to have any effect.

**UPDATE:** Based on ppotaczek's answer below, here's what I did to turn off tooltips for all regression lines on the chart:

```
Highcharts.chart('mychart', {
    // ...
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var trendlines = this.series.filter(c => c.options.isRegressionLine);
            for (i in trendlines) {
                trendlines[i].update({
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                });
            }
        }
    },
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `highcharts-regression` plugin is not official Highcharts plugin, but please look at the documentation: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.tooltip, you can not disable tooltip for individual series in the way you try. You should use `enableMouseTracking` property, but it is not supported in `regressionSettings`. To workaround, you can use `update` method on created regression series in this way:

```
            load: function() {
                this.series[1].update({
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                });
            }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dt42v3uz/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.enableMouseTracking

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in documentation [HIGHCHARTS REGRESSION](https://www.highcharts.com/products/plugin-registry/single/22/Highcharts%20regression) the tooltip object fellow the stander configuration of highchart disabling or enabling for the entire chart.
unless you want to search the generated html/css and remove the tooltips with jquery.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that.  In my jsfiddle, I am setting "enabled: false" on the tooltip, which I believe is the standard way to hide the tooltips (at least according to the API reference at https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.enabled).  Can you tell why that isn't working?

Comment: the library doesn't support this feature. you may want to fork the project and modify the source code.